# How to know what guitar to buy for a C F C F A# D G tuning?

Tags: guitar, alternative-tunings, metal

For some months I've been quite obsessed with the sound of some djent metal groups.

Bought a 7-string guitar with the largest scale length I could afford along with an 8 string pack, the thickest one being a .80. I did not reach my desired note at all; still quite happy with the guitar.

I'm still willing to spend more if that would get me to my desired note, but I'm really having a hard time understanding what I'm missing and by how much.

The 7-string had a 686 / 648 mm scale length (fanned frets), and I was using a .80 string.

The tuning I was aiming for seems to be: C F C F A# D G

I'm no music expert at all but I think that's a C1. Could I achieve that with some bass strings? Do I need a different (longer scale, baritone) guitar, or do djent players only achieve this with post-processing effects?

Comment: Are you sure they're actually tuning to C1?  It's certainly possible, but I don't know of a single song tuned that low, and drop C at C2 is an incredibly common metal tuning.

Comment: Yes, nik solved my doubts https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kj49Fl1moEQ, i was mainly interested in "within the ruins"

Comment: .84 is *very* heavy for any string! Do you mean 0.084"?

Comment: true, i checked the string pack, it is a Ernie Ball 2624, 9-80 isn´t it a .80 then? indeed it is very heavy but seems like it´s not enought

Comment: C1 would be a (rather low) bass note, so maybe you need a six string bass? You'll never get there on any neck with common guitar scale-lengths. Are you sure C1 is the note you are actually hearing played (by the guitar)?

Comment: @GeraldMoore does the video from nik serve as proof? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kj49Fl1moEQ

Comment: I didn't watch it or notice your comment until now. I've got a Bass VI reissue with (iirc .094 on the low E) and it flops around like crazy tuned to C1. It probably sounds fine with that much disto but you've got to really play well to avoid playing out of tune.

Comment: I'll note that the cited video of nik's has him playing with an **8-string guitar**, not a 7-string one.

Comment: I play in a totally different style, so not answering, but for reference, my 5-string bass has .130 B string and a 875 mm scale length, and that's only a semitone lower than you want to go.

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about tuning to double-drop c on a seven-string, which is the equivalent of playing drop F on a six-string. It's *technically* doable, but there's a better tool for the job. Realistically you should buy a nine-string if you want to play double-drop music and can afford one.